# Joining an LSTM with a parallel MLP network with embedding layers

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to build the LSTM model with a parallel input for the nontime dependent variable. Some of these variables are categorical in nature and I would like to create pass them through an embedding layer and then join with the LSTM later on.

Please see below the code I am trying out but I am getting an error of "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

> The following is a code that I have written as of now.

```
model = Model(inputs=[cat_els, ts_inputs], outputs=out_class)
```

> My cat_els is defined as (list of 3 tensors):

```
[<tf.Tensor 'flatten_10/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'flatten_11/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'flatten_12/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>]
```

> ts_inputs is defined as:

```
<tf.Tensor 'input_3:0' shape=(?, 6, 17) dtype=float32>
```

> Error Traceback

```
 File "<ipython-input-48-601f97a5b348>", line 31, in <module>
    model = Model(inputs=[cat_els, ts_inputs], outputs=out_class)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 147, in _init_graph_network
    if len(set(self.inputs)) != len(self.inputs):

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can anyone please tell me what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: can you confirm type(cat_els) and see if it needs to be an array?

Comment: @SteveB: cat_els is a list. it is a list of tensors
[<tf.Tensor 'flatten_10/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'flatten_11/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'flatten_12/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras does not support inputs that are lists of input layers themselves, the input list needs to contain input layers, you can do this by just concatenating your inputs:

```
model = Model(inputs=cat_els + [ts_inputs], outputs=out_class)
```

Then this model will have 4 input layers.

Comment: Thanks a lot worked like a charm, I need to learn a lot more basics of these things :)